# ltablex caption text formatting issue

Tags: tables, formatting, captions, tabularx, ltablex

I'm using the `ltablex` package for creating long tables over multiple pages. For my other small tables I use the `tabularx` package and I noticed a formatting mistake or maybe a bug?

The table caption text of my long table created does not flush correctly with the `bottomrule` line.

When you run the code you will see that the caption at the bottom of the small table flushes correctly with the `bottomrule` line. But on the long table the caption text did not flush correctly with the `bottomrule` line. There the text stands out a little bit at the left side.

When i use my small table with out the `\begin{table]` and `\end{table}` Environment and put the caption inside the `tabularx`, the same issue as on the long table appears, so how can I get it right working on the long table. I can not use there the `\begin{table]` and `\end{table}` Environment, So is there an other way to get the caption text formatted like on my small table with the `\begin{table]` and `\end{table}` Environment?

I Added two pictures of it. The first one shows a piece of the long table and the second the small table.

[image]
[image]

**EDIT - Full Code**

```
\documentclass[%
a4paper,
12pt,                   
oneside,
captions=nooneline,
parskip=half
]
{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
%\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{mathptmx}% Times

\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalfont\bfseries}
\setkomafont{caption}{\fontsize{9pt}{9pt}\selectfont}

\begin{document}

\keepXColumns
\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XX}
\toprule
\textbf{Column 1} & \textbf{Column 2} \\
\midrule
$R$ & 1This is an example sentence \\
$R$ & 2As well as the line before \\
$A$ & 3Also this is an example \\
$R$ & 4This is an example sentence \\
$R$ & 5As well as the line before \\
$A$ & 6Also this is an example \\
$R$ & 7This is an example sentence \\
$R$ & 8As well as the line before \\
$A$ & 9Also this is an example \\
$R$ & 10This is an example sentence \\
$R$ & 11As well as the line before \\
$A$ & 12Also this is an example \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}  
\caption{Example of an table} 
\end{table}

\newpage

\keepXColumns
%\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XX}
\toprule
\textbf{Column 1} & \textbf{Column 2} \\
\midrule
$R$ & 1This is an example sentence \\
$R$ & 2As well as the line before \\
$A$ & 3Also this is an example \\
$R$ & 4This is an example sentence \\
$R$ & 5As well as the line before \\
$A$ & 6Also this is an example \\
$R$ & 7This is an example sentence \\
$R$ & 8As well as the line before \\
$A$ & 9Also this is an example \\
$R$ & 10This is an example sentence \\
$R$ & 11As well as the line before \\
$A$ & 12Also this is an example \\
$R$ & 13This is an example sentence \\
$R$ & 14As well as the line before \\
$A$ & 15Also this is an example \\
$R$ & 16This is an example sentence \\
$R$ & 17As well as the line before \\
$A$ & 18Also this is an example \\
$R$ & 19This is an example sentence \\
$R$ & 20As well as the line before \\
$A$ & 21Also this is an example \\
$R$ & 22This is an example sentence \\
$R$ & 23As well as the line before \\
$A$ & 24Also this is an example \\
$R$ & 25This is an example sentence \\
$R$ & 26As well as the line before \\
$A$ & 27Also this is an example \\
$R$ & 28This is an example sentence \\
$R$ & 29As well as the line before \\
$A$ & 30Also this is an example \\
$R$ & 31This is an example sentence \\
$R$ & 32As well as the line before \\
$A$ & 33Also this is an example \\
$R$ & 34This is an example sentence \\
$R$ & 35As well as the line before \\
$A$ & 36Also this is an example \\
$R$ & 37This is an example sentence \\
$R$ & 1This is an example sentence \\
$R$ & 2As well as the line before \\
$A$ & 3Also this is an example \\
$R$ & 4This is an example sentence \\
$R$ & 5As well as the line before \\
$A$ & 6Also this is an example \\
$R$ & 7This is an example sentence \\
$R$ & 8As well as the line before \\
$A$ & 9Also this is an example \\
$R$ & 10This is an example sentence \\
$R$ & 11As well as the line before \\
$A$ & 12Also this is an example \\
$R$ & 13This is an example sentence \\
$R$ & 14As well as the line before \\
$A$ & 15Also this is an example \\
$R$ & 16This is an example sentence \\
$R$ & 17As well as the line before \\
$A$ & 18Also this is an example \\
$R$ & 19This is an example sentence \\
$R$ & 20As well as the line before \\
$A$ & 21Also this is an example \\
$R$ & 22This is an example sentence \\
$R$ & 23As well as the line before \\
$A$ & 24Also this is an example \\
$R$ & 25This is an example sentence \\
$R$ & 26As well as the line before \\
$A$ & 27Also this is an example \\
$R$ & 28This is an example sentence \\
$R$ & 29As well as the line before \\
$A$ & 30Also this is an example \\
$R$ & 31This is an example sentence \\
$R$ & 32As well as the line before \\
$A$ & 33Also this is an example \\
$R$ & 34This is an example sentence \\
$R$ & 35As well as the line before \\
$A$ & 36Also this is an example \\
$R$ & 37This is an example sentence \\
\bottomrule
\caption{Example of an table2} 
\end{tabularx}  

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

use

```
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalfont\bfseries}
\setkomafont{caption}{\small}    
\begin{document}

\keepXColumns
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Xx}\toprule
        \textbf{Column 1} & \textbf{Column 2} \\\midrule
        $R$ & 1This is an example sentence \\
        $R$ & 2As well as the line before \\
        $A$ & 3Also this is an example \\
        $R$ & 4This is an example sentence \\
        $R$ & 5As well as the line before \\
        $A$ & 6Also this is an example \\
        $R$ & 7This is an example sentence \\
        $R$ & 8As well as the line before \\
        $A$ & 9Also this is an example \\
        $R$ & 10This is an example sentence \\
        $R$ & 11As well as the line before \\
        $A$ & 12Also this is an example \\
        \bottomrule
    \caption{Example of an table} \\
    \end{tabularx}  

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XX}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Column 1} & \textbf{Column 2} \\
    \midrule
    $R$ & 1This is an example sentence \\
    $R$ & 2As well as the line before \\
    [...]
```

The caption must be inside the `tabularx`. And do *not* use the environment `table` for the `tabularx`. It has its own `table` counter .

[image]

[image]

Comment: did not make any changes to it. i Edited my post and added the full code. Hope this helps.

Comment: see edited answer. And, by the way, the counting is correct ;-)

Comment: you removed the \begin{tabe} tag i see. One possible solution :) But i want the padding of the caption like i have the \begin{table} tag there and the \caption tag after the \end{tabularx}. Is there a way to get this result on the long table? and which is the correct way to add a caption to tables and figures. Inside the \table and \figure tag (like you did it) or after it (like on my first table) ? :)

Comment: With `table`  you get a wrong counting of the tables! It makes no sense to use it in such a environment when using `ltablex`!  Only a default `tabular` environment should be inside `table`

Comment: good to know, i thought the \table tag must be there every time. So i will remove the table stuff from all my other tables and have a look how it looks like then with the caption thing and will report it.

Comment: i did it ans see that the caption text is not flushing with the line. The text is some millimeter to wide left form the beginning of the bottomrule line. How can i add some padding to the caption to that the caption starts corectly with the line? For example i have 3cm padding on the left paper side before the the text starts, but now the caption starts at 2,85 cm and the bottomline at 3cm. But both should start at 3cm.

Comment: I cannot see that. The above images are created with your example! However, I prefer a column setting like `{ @{} XX @{} }`

Comment: Yes and there you can See that the caption is over the vertical line in the left side. But there should be a little padding between the line and the text

Comment: With package `caption`: `\captionsetup{margin=1pt}`

Answer (score 2):

The caption must be incorporated in the table – just as with `longtable`, inside the `foot` specifications, if you want the caption at the bottoms of the table, or in the `head` soecifications to have it above the table (which is recommended).

Also, if you load `ltablex`, you don't have to load `tabularx` nor `longtable` since they're loaded by ltablex.

```
    \documentclass[a4paper]{article}%
    \usepackage{ltablex, booktabs}
    \usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \captionsetup[table]{singlelinecheck=off, position=bottom}
     \usepackage{etoolbox}

    \begin{document}

    \keepXColumns
     \begin{table}[htbp]
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XX}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Column 1} & \textbf{Column 2} \\
    \midrule
    $R$ & 1This is an example sentence \\
    $R$ & 2As well as the line before \\
    $A$ & 3Also this is an example \\
    $R$ & 4This is an example sentence \\
    $R$ & 5As well as the line before \\
    $A$ & 6Also this is an example \\
    $R$ & 7This is an example sentence \\
    $R$ & 8As well as the line before \\
    $A$ & 9Also this is an example \\
    $R$ & 10This is an example sentence \\
    $R$ & 11As well as the line before \\
    $A$ & 12Also this is an example \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \caption{Example of an table}
    \end{table}

    \bigskip
    {\pretocmd{\tablename}{\,}{}{}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XX}
    \midrule
    \caption{Example of an table}\label{xyz}
    \endfoot
    \bottomrule
    \caption{Example of an table}
    \endlastfoot
    \toprule
    \textbf{Column 1} & \textbf{Column 2} \\
    \midrule
    $R$ & 1This is an example sentence \\
    $R$ & 2As well as the line before \\
    $A$ & 3Also this is an example \\
    $R$ & 4This is an example sentence \\
    $R$ & 5As well as the line before \\
    $A$ & 6Also this is an example \\
    $R$ & 7This is an example sentence \\
    $R$ & 8As well as the line before \\
    $A$ & 9Also this is an example \\
    $R$ & 10This is an example sentence \\
    $R$ & 11As well as the line before \\
    $A$ & 12Also this is an example \\
    $R$ & 13This is an example sentence \\
    $R$ & 14As well as the line before \\
    $A$ & 15Also this is an example \\
    $R$ & 16This is an example sentence \\
    $R$ & 17As well as the line before \\
    $A$ & 18Also this is an example \\
    $R$ & 19This is an example sentence \\
    $R$ & 20As well as the line before \\
    $A$ & 21Also this is an example \\
    $R$ & 22This is an example sentence \\
    $R$ & 23As well as the line before \\
    $A$ & 24Also this is an example \\
    $R$ & 25This is an example sentence \\
    $R$ & 26As well as the line before \\
    $A$ & 27Also this is an example \\
    $R$ & 28This is an example sentence \\
    $R$ & 29As well as the line before \\
    $A$ & 30Also this is an example \\
    $R$ & 31This is an example sentence \\
    $R$ & 32As well as the line before \\
    $A$ & 33Also this is an example \\
    $R$ & 34This is an example sentence \\
    $R$ & 35As well as the line before \\
    $A$ & 36Also this is an example \\
    $R$ & 37This is an example sentence \\
    $R$ & 1This is an example sentence \\
    $R$ & 2As well as the line before \\
    $A$ & 3Also this is an example \\
    $R$ & 4This is an example sentence \\
    $R$ & 5As well as the line before \\
    $A$ & 6Also this is an example \\
    $R$ & 7This is an example sentence \\
    $R$ & 8As well as the line before \\
    $A$ & 9Also this is an example \\
    $R$ & 10This is an example sentence \\
    $R$ & 11As well as the line before \\
    $A$ & 12Also this is an example \\
    $R$ & 13This is an example sentence \\
    $R$ & 14As well as the line before \\
    $A$ & 15Also this is an example \\
    $R$ & 16This is an example sentence \\
    $R$ & 17As well as the line before \\
    $A$ & 18Also this is an example \\
    $R$ & 19This is an example sentence \\
    $R$ & 20As well as the line before \\
    $A$ & 21Also this is an example \\
    $R$ & 22This is an example sentence \\
    $R$ & 23As well as the line before \\
    $A$ & 24Also this is an example \\
    $R$ & 25This is an example sentence \\
    $R$ & 26As well as the line before \\
    $A$ & 27Also this is an example \\
    $R$ & 28This is an example sentence \\
    $R$ & 29As well as the line before \\
    $A$ & 30Also this is an example \\
    $R$ & 31This is an example sentence \\
    $R$ & 32As well as the line before \\
    $A$ & 33Also this is an example \\
    $R$ & 34This is an example sentence \\
    $R$ & 35As well as the line before \\
    $A$ & 36Also this is an example \\
    $R$ & 37This is an example sentence
    \end{tabularx}}

    \end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: as you can see on your own screenshots, the caption of the long table is to wide left aligned. I want it like on the small table. it should be flush with the bottomline.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean. To me, it is like in your post. Could you explain in more details?

Comment: i don't want it like on my post. I want the caption of the long table to be aligned with the bottomrule line of the table. In your and my screenshost you can see that on the small table caption flushes in one line with the bottomrule line but on the long table the caption flushes not correctly with the bottomrule line. The "T" of "Table 3: Example of an table" is some milimeters to wide left; on the small table it matches correctly. The "T" on you images goes out of the box of the long table screenshot, in the small table screenshots not - can you see it? And i want it like on the small table.

Comment: It seems to be a bug, not sure whether it's longtable or ltablex. I added a work-around with `etoolbox`, just before the long table (`\pretocmd{tablename]·`).

Comment: yes did fix it, too. Is there a way to make apply the command global for all tables?

Comment: I'm  afarid not, as it is not required for short `tabularx`s, and I don't how to make a difference in the code. Maybe defining a `mytabularx` environment which incorporates the small patch and will be used only if the table is more than one page long.

Comment: ok. i do it now with \captionsetup{margin=1pt} which fixes the problem. the problem applies because of the removed vertical lines. when i create a full table with the whole grid lines there is no problem, but if i remove all the vertical lines the problem appears, but with \captionsetup{margin=1pt} i can margin the caption so that it matches with the bottom line.

Comment: That's a fine solution.

Answer (score 2):

The solution for my problem is to use `\captionsetup{margin=1pt}` with the caption package. With 2pt i got the correct alignment of the caption.

thanks to [Herbert](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/292032/ltablex-caption-text-formatting-issue#comment707192_292036)!

or as alternative when using Komascript - like me - the command `\setcapmargin{2pt}` will do the same.